# Refreshing PowerApps SP form after Submit

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, powerapps-forms, refresh

I have a PowerApps form, which is a Customized SP list form.  Each time I submit an item via PowerApps form, if I immediately click "New" again on the list, some data still displays in my form.  I added a Refresh(Datasource) action to the Form's OnSuccess property, but that same issue remains.  Is there another way I can force the form to Refresh after each submission?  The idea is that the Users will be submitting several items back to back, and I don't want them to have to refresh the List page each time they want to create a new item.

Thank you!